# ui testing xcode, how to tap on a table view cell button with cellquery

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I am currently doing ui tests for my app and stuck on clicking on the log in button of my app. I am unable to find the element which i have gave the identifier signup button(the element is the 3rd by index, this is not the issue).

```
let cellQuery = self.app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 3)

let signInButton = cellQuery.buttons["signup button"]
if signInButton.exists {
    signInButton.tap()
}
```

Comment: A link to a screenshot and a dump of the output of `signInButton.debugDescription` would be helpful for context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the button is present in the 3rd cell then it should be:

```
let cellQuery = self.app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 2)
cellQuery.buttons["signup button"].tap()
```

If button is 3rd in the cell then add accessibility for the cells and then:

```
app.cells["AccessibilityIdentifier"].buttons.element(boundBy: 2).tap()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this:

```
XCUIApplication().tables.cells.element(boundBy: 2).buttons["signup button"].tap()
```

Comment: This will fail in localized apps. Please consider accessibility identifiers as the locale-agnostic way to handle this.